# How to fix shaking on animations

Tags: css

Hello guys i have problem with this project. There is shaking in picture while scale animation is happening. backface-visibility did not solved problem can any body help please?

Here is in codepen. sorry for bad english.
https://codepen.io/blackbicoder/pen/QXRaNB

```
<div class="portfolio__item">
  <div class="portfolio__picture">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2617751/pexels-photo-2617751.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beverage-business-coffee-2617751.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Portfolio image 1" class="portfolio__img">
    <div class="portfolio__overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.portfolio__item {
  width: 30rem;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__overlay,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__img,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
.portfolio__picture {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}
.portfolio__img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.portfolio__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, looks smooth to me

Comment: in firefox works perfect but in chrome it shakes on my pc. what ever thanx dude i will check when i publish site

Comment: did you try making backface-visibility: visible?

Comment: yeah did not work

Comment: does it can be because of prefixes?

Comment: Even I tried with several elements and I think by adding blue to 0 within the image gave an almost less shake.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following line right after `backface-visibility: hidden;`

```
-webkit-filter: blur(0);
```

This would work almost for the requirement. Because this is transition running while in another transition.

```css
.portfolio__item {
  width: 30rem;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__overlay,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.portfolio__item:hover .portfolio__img,
.portfolio__item:focus .portfolio__img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.portfolio__picture {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.portfolio__img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.3s, filter 0.3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}

.portfolio__overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__item">
  <div class="portfolio__picture">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2617751/pexels-photo-2617751.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beverage-business-coffee-2617751.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Portfolio image 1" class="portfolio__img">
    <div class="portfolio__overlay">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @black check this code, I hope this would solve it. I ran it on my chrome and opera browsers.

Comment: in this code snippet i still have shaking :(. my first project really good starting huh with perfect bugs :D

Comment: also shaking on project on my pc )

Comment: @Black to be clear, the issue is that after the mouse hover ends, the image takes a bit shaking to display the texts in the image right? and when you add visible,  it takes a delay to become blur after focusing. That's what you meant by shaking right?

Comment: when i stop hovering on image image shakes on my project. can i send video in here ? any way to add screen record?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aq10owJlOlswhmfwWB2Npc1CB4Z-

here is video capture of my screen. u can see there when i stop hovering picture picture jumps a bit and then comes to original position